# Django: How to get an amount of posts from db in a ListView

Tags: django

I have this ListView and at now it takes every Car obj from database and posts in homepage, how do i limit to only take an x amount of posts?

```py
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-created']
    paginate_by = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your `get_queryset` method and limit your results there.

```
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-created']
    paginate_by = 6
    limit = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Car.objects.all()[:self.limit] # or this could be hardcoded to whatever number you'd like to
```